# how to deploy rails project with RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2

I want to run the rails project having RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' I have some of my running project with rails version is 3.2.11....how do I proceede

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Gemfile and replace the rails gem line with :

```
gem "rails", "2.3.8"
```

Comment: I have complete project in rails 2.8.3 but i want to deploy it on my server which have some projects running in 3.2.11.

Comment: Are you using rvm? You can control what version of ruby you want to use with rvm. You can also specify which version of gems you want to use by creating a gemset for a particular project. More info here on gemsets : https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics